# Hide when uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code has a javascript that allows to display a dropdown when Input Bracket is checked,When I unclick the Input Bracket It doesn't hide the displayed dropdown.Sorry if this was so the same with the other post, but they don't work for me.

Here's the code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" <?php if (isset($ab) && $ab=="20") echo "checked";?> value="20">20s
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" <?php if (isset($ab) && $ab=="30") echo "checked";?> value="30">30s
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" <?php if (isset($ab) && $ab=="40") echo "checked";?> value="40">40s                             
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" <?php if (isset($ab) && $ab=="50") echo "checked";?> value="50">50s                             
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="all") echo "checked";?> value="All" onClick="toggle3(this)">All Ages
<br>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ib" id="bracket" value="All">Input Bracket
<br>
<div id='input-bracket'>
<select  name="sab"  class="req"  id="age-range" style="width:50px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/> </select> -
<select  name="sab"  class="req"  id="second" style="width:50px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/> </select></div>

$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#input-bracket").hide();
 $("input[class=ba]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "bracket") {
      $("#input-bracket").show();
    } else {
      $("#input-bracket").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would it hide it?  The logic says to show it in the scenario you just described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually figuring out when to show or hide element let jquery do it for you with it's 'toggle' api http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#input-bracket").hide();
 $("input[class=ba]").click(function() {
    $("#input-bracket").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: when I checked the other's it also shows the input-bracket :(

Comment: oh alright I figured it out, I need to remove the class="ba" from other checkboxes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#input-bracket").hide();
  $("#bracket").click(function() {
    if ($("#input-bracket").is(":visible")) {
      $("#input-bracket").hide();
    } else {
      $("#input-bracket").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" value="20">20s
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" value="30">30s
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" value="40">40s
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" value="50">50s
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ab" value="All" onClick="toggle3(this)">All Ages
<br>

<input type="checkbox" class="ba" name="ib" id="bracket" value="All">Input Bracket
<br>
<div id='input-bracket'>
  <select name="sab" class="req" id="age-range" style="width:50px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/></select>-
  <select name="sab" class="req" id="second" style="width:50px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/></select>
</div>
```

Comment: when I checked the other's it also shows the input-bracket :(